# How to retrieve information from an object I put into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a class:

```
public Inventario (int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage sprite, String frutas) {}
```

This classe is to show an image (with width and height) at the x, y point on the screen. The sprite is the image itself and the String is my attempt of getting information by the name of the image saved.

So I add some objects to this class and put each object into an array list called "itensInventario":

```
 Inventario ban = new Inventario(63, 27, 6, 6, sheet.getSprite(121, 171, 6, 6), "banana"); 
                
 itensInventario.add(ban);  


Inventario cen = new Inventario(10, 96, 6, 6, sheet.getSprite(121, 178, 6, 6), "cenoura");  
                    
itensInventario.add(cen);
```

The question is: how do I retrieve the String name of each object I put into the arraylist?

I tried to do something like this:

```
        for(int i=0; i< Game.itensInventario.size(); i++) {
        
        System.out.println("Show: " + Game.itensInventario.get(i));}
```

But I don't know how exactly get the String for each index "i".

EDIT:

Inventário class (maybe it doesn't help. I tried to make a method GetFruta but in the end all objects would be with the same name in String so I gave up it but it still there):

public class Inventario

{

```
public int dx;
public int dy;
public BufferedImage [] itens;  

public static String fruta;


public Inventario (int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage sprite, String frutas) {


    itens = new BufferedImage [2];  
    itens[0] = Game.sheet.getSprite(121, 171, 6, 6); //Banana
    itens[1] = Game.sheet.getSprite(121, 178, 6, 6); //Cenoura
    
    fruta = frutas;
    

    
}


public void setFruta(String novaFruta) {this.fruta = novaFruta;}
public String getFruta() {return fruta;}


public void tick() {
    

    
    for(int i=0; i< Game.itensInventario.size(); i++) {
        
        System.out.println("esse: " + Game.itensInventario.get(i)+ " index: " +Game.itensInventario.get(i)+ "\n\n");}
            
    
   
    
}







public void render(Graphics g)
{
    
            
     
        if(Game.itensInventario.size() >0) {
            
  if( this==Game.itensInventario.get(0) ){         
       if(Game.itensInventario.get(0).getFruta() == "banana") { g.drawImage(itens[0], 63, Game.HEIGHT-27, null); }
       else if(Game.itensInventario.get(0).getFruta() == "cenoura")  { g.drawImage(itens[1], 63, Game.HEIGHT-27, null); }        
  } 
   
    
   if(Game.itensInventario.size() >1) {
  if(this==Game.itensInventario.get(1) ){          
       if(Game.itensInventario.get(1).getFruta() == "banana") {  g.drawImage(itens[0], 70, Game.HEIGHT-27, null);}
       else if(Game.itensInventario.get(1).getFruta() == "cenoura")  { g.drawImage(itens[1], 70, Game.HEIGHT-27, null); }        
   } 
   
   }
   
        
    }
    


}
```

}

EDIT 2

I created this way the arraylist (List of objects from the class Inventario, ecah object has a String, right? Once I put this String in a new object how do I retrieve it?):

```
 public static List<Inventario>itensInventario;
 itensInventario = new ArrayList<Inventario>();
```

Comment: Can you include the full `Inventario` class? Just so I can give a better answer.

Comment: Your class doesn't look like a class -- the code you shared looks like it might be the constructor for a class, but one that throws away all the data.

Comment: Plus, is your ArrayList typed or is it a raw one? Please show more detail so we can help you further.

Comment: Maybe ``Game.itensInventario.get(i).toString()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get your `frutas` string, then it is as simple as

```
Game.itensInventario.get(i).getFruta();
```

However at the moment your `fruta` field in the `Inventario` class is static, which means it doesn't belong to that specific instance and is instead a shared variable amongst all instances. So removing the static modifier should solve your problem.

---

I would recommend taking a look at a Java tutorial to get a good grasp of some of the basics on static variables, like here: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: I tried this but when I run the for, all the objects are with the same name on the String field. Always the name of the last object added.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: You are right. I did the most dificult and didn't notice the basic stuff... Thank you a lot. I didn't meant to ask a simple question but when your brain is burning you ask...

Comment: Always the basics that catch you out! Good luck with your project.